# <= less than equal to does't work as expected for sequilize query in nodejs

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have the following query in sequilize.js

```
const [results] = await sequelize.query(`select DISTINCT ON (variant_id) variant_id, Count(wl) as count, pds.name AS name,
  CASE
      WHEN pvs.name is NULL THEN pds.name
      ELSE pvs.name
  END 
  as variant_name,
  im.url as img_url
from wish_lists as wl
LEFT JOIN products AS pds ON pds.id = wl.product_id
LEFT JOIN images as im on im.product_id = wl.product_id
LEFT JOIN product_variants as pvs ON pvs.id = wl.variant_id
where wl.created_at >= '${startDate}' AND wl.created_at <= '${endDate}' AND wl.tenant_id=${merchant_id}
group by ( variant_id, pds.name, im.url, pvs.name) LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0`)
```

The problem is if today is the 20th and i have products in the db that are selected on the 20th the query does't include those even though i have `<=` for the endDate, why is that ?

So why is the same day entries not being selected ?

Comment: I'm not up to speed on node and postgresql, but it looks like you are *almost* using parameters but instead just inject values into the sql command - please find out how to really use parameters

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, take a look at timezone of datetime data in database and in query param.

Secondly, `created_at` is the timestamp, which contain Time data (for example 2019-12-20T01:20:30.000Z). Then, your query param ${endDate} is just Date data only, it will append time = 0 (which is 00:00:00.000) before the comparison.

So the comparison would look like:

```
2019-12-20T01:20:30.000Z  <= 2019-12-20T00:00:00.000Z
```

And the result is false, then it cannot be selected.

Comment: instead of `<= {today}`, use `< {tomorrow}`

Comment: @HansKeﬆing unfortunatly thats not an option , devs or testers are gonna pickup on that sooner or later

Comment: @Huy for some wierd reason managed to resolve it with `where to_date(wl.created_at::TEXT,'YYYY-MM-DD') >= '${startDate}' AND to_date(wl.created_at::TEXT,'YYYY-MM-DD') <= '${endDate}'`

Comment: If you can add the above to your answer , i'll accept !

Comment: you were correct in your analysis about timezones btw , its just i know so very little about it ! :)

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik that solution will lead to a full table scan: convert every stored date to a date-string, then compare. It works because that date-string doesn't contain a time

Comment: and of course, for "tomorrow" in `< {tomorrow}` read: "endDate + 1" (as in: the record's created_at should be *before* midnight the day *after* the specified enddate)